# How to store/access large data set with HTML5 for use offline?

Tags: html

I want to make an HTML5 app that can be used offline that accesses a database of words. However, I don't know the proper way to store this data initially. For example, if I wanted to create a spell checker that compared words typed with a dictionary database (thousands of words), how would I store the database of words? This is just an example of what I might want to do, the underlying question is how to create such a database to begin with that can be accessed offline.

Comment: Please do not use 'best' in your question as that is subjective, and please choose one question, not two.

Comment: "Best" by what criteria?

Comment: I am open to suggestions. :) By best I mean most efficient for a database that is not small (i.e. thousands of words).

Comment: Edited question to more appropriately fit SO's format.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) API which holds up to 5 MB.  Use local storage if you want data to persist across browser tabs and sessions or session storage for session scope.  You may also want to consider [client-side database storage](http://www.webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/).